# Boost crawler - maximum time to use for crawling on every cron run?

Tags: performance, cron, caching

I have a drupal 7 site. The site is really big and has few content types, and a lot of content.
I use boost and Cache expiration to improve performance.

I will be happy to get some information regarding the crawler of Boost.
I want to Pre-cache as much pages of the website as I can, so they get cached before anyone accesses them.

what is the maximum recommended time (in seconds) to use for crawling on every cron run?

Answer (score 0):

I am using it, and 30 second enough.